# Negative References or reversing order of column for DATEDIF

Tags: google-sheets

I have a ascending sorted list of irregular dates in Column A:A:

```
A           B   C   D (A:A,A2:A)   E (A:A,A3:A)
2017-11-09  10  10  NA             NA 
2017-11-10  11  21  1              NA
2017-11-14  15  36  4              5
2017-11-15  22  58  1              5
```

Column C:C is a rolling sum of B:B. I'm trying to get arrayformula in D:D/E:E to find the datedif between current row (starting date) and X rows above (end date):

```
=ArrayFormula(DATEDIF(B:B-(X Rows),B:B,"D"))
```

The goal is to find range of change in D:D over X amount of days:

```
D:D - D:D-rowX / datedif (A:A-rowX, A:A)
```

i.e for 2 days on row C4:

```
(C4-C2) / datedif(C4-2,C4,"D")
(58-21) / datedif(C2,C4,"D")
37 / 5 = 7.4
```

for 5 days on row C10:

```
(C10-C5) / datedif(C10-5,C10,"D")
```

for 15 days on row C20:

```
(C20-C5) / datedif(C20-15,C20,"D")
```

I'm trying to calculate X for 1,2,3,4,7,28 rows up which means the array has to start that 1,2,3,4,7,28 rows down.

Right now, the array bugs out to bad reference because the first starting date is DATEDIF(B-X,B1,"D") where B-X is a invalid negative reference. Arrayformulas with bad values instead of bad references seems to just skip past errors and starts working once input are valid. But I can't figure out how to skip bad references. I've tried forcing start date with `INDIRECT` but can't get it to recognize value as a date. I also tried `DATEDIF(B:B, B:B+X,"D")`, which spits out the correct numbers but results are offset by X rows. I've tried reverse sorting A:A, `=ArrayFormula(if(len(A:A),DATEDIF(SORT(A2:A,1,0),SORT(A:A,1,0),"D"),""))` it produces a reverse orders list of correct answers that I can't figure out how to flip back.

Seems like I'm missing something obvious?

EDIT: tried to clarify original post

Is there a easy way to displace an entire column?
Alternative Solution?

The formula roughly works but is not aligned to the correct row:

```
C D E
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2
1
```

I just need it to display

```
C D E
1
1 2
1 2 3 
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

To get things aligned, I can put in cell on row2  of Column F:

```
=array_constrain(ARRAYFORMULA(D:D),COUNT(A:A)-2,1)
```

Or cell in row3 of Column G:

```
=array_constrain(ARRAYFORMULA(E:E),COUNT(A:A)-3,1)
```

But if I try trigger teh formula from row1 via:

```
=arrayformula(if(row(A:A)>=2,array_constrain(D:D,COUNT(A:A)-2,1)))
```

It label everythign >=2 row false and still render D:D without displacing the cells the proper number of rows:

```
C D 
1 false
1 2 
1 2 
1 2
1
```

EDIT: I'm closing the request, ended up just using vlookup(B:B-X) which provided an approximate enough result to work for my needs.

Comment: @Rubén, whoops, typo for datedif.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

Add the following formula to D1

`=ArrayFormula({"N/A";ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(DATEDIF(A:A,A2:A,"D"),COUNT(A:A)-1,1)})`

And the following formula to E1

`=ArrayFormula({"N/A";"N/A";ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(DATEDIF(A:A,A3:A,"D"),COUNT(A:A)-2,1)})`

## Explanation

The solution use ARRAY_CONSTRAIN to return just the required result values and use a the array notation to add the required N/A values for the rows that as it don't have a pair to calculate the date difference.

REMARK:

Please note that the DATEDIF functions use the column A for the references as this column is the one that holds the date values.

Comment: Thank you, my issue is the solution does not offset array the correct number of rows if enddate is B3+:B (or more). I've appended a column in the original to show desired behavior. For example:

`=ArrayFormula({"N/A";ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(DATEDIF(B:B,B3:B,"D"),COUNT(B:B)-2,1)})`, the array constrain should start on row 3. I've tried array_constrain before where I attempted to offset the datedif array with `if(row(A:A >=3, then execute datedif`, but couldn't get the syntax to work.

Comment: Regarding the IF syntax, see [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)